# Java shortest path to 1

Tags: java

**Old program**

```
public class JavaApplication7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = ""; // any given whole positive integer
        long solution = 0;
        double t = Double.parseDouble(n);
        double pow = nearpow(t);
        double nearpow = Math.pow(2, nearpow(t));
        double difference = Math.abs(t-nearpow);
        while(t!=1){
            if(t==nearpow){
                solution+=pow;
                t/=nearpow;
            }
            if(nearpow<t&&t!=1){
                t = t - difference;                 
                solution+=difference;
                t = t / nearpow;
                solution+=pow;                
            }
            else if(nearpow>t&&t!=1){
                t+=difference;                
                solution+=difference;      
                t/=nearpow;
                solution+=pow;
                }
            }
        System.out.println(solution);
    } 
    public static double nearpow(double t){
        double log = Math.log(t) / Math.log(2);

        long roundLog = Math.round(log);
        double dec = Math.abs(log-roundLog);
        long lowPow = (long)(log-dec);
        long highPow = lowPow+1;
        if(Math.abs(t-Math.pow(2,highPow))<Math.abs(t-Math.pow(2,lowPow))){
            return highPow;
        }
        else{
            return lowPow;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm programming to find the lowest number of operations to make a number down to 1 with the limited operations of +1 -1 and /2, the test works for the cases I've used (4, 5, 15, 30, 35, 60 values, however it fails to operate with higher valued values. Can anyone see the point of failure for higher values an example is 726 gives a 259 operations to get to 1.

**New Program**

```
    String n = "54123";
    BigInteger t = new BigInteger(n);
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    System.out.println(t);
    int solution =0;       
    while(!t.equals(one)){
        if(((t.and(one)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))){
            System.out.println(t+"/2 =");
            t=t.shiftRight(1);
            solution++;  
            }
        else if((t.and(one)).equals(BigInteger.ONE)&&(((t.shiftRight(1).and(one))).equals(BigInteger.ONE))&&(((t.shiftRight(2).and(one))).equals(BigInteger.ONE))){
            System.out.println(t+"+2 =");
            t=t.add(one);
            solution++;

        }
        else if(t.and(one).shiftRight(1).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)&&t.and(one).equals(one)){
            System.out.println(t+"-1 =");
            t=t.subtract(one);            
            solution++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(solution);
```

I am very new to bitwise operation so I need a little help with finding the new fault of the problem since what I wrote is still very new to me and to add to the new use of bitwise operation I have to write it in BigInteger which the terms are very difficult for me to understand, however the with the terms I'm using It should work but i cant find a reason as to why it wouldn't, the example used before was 762 that gave 259 operations and with the new program it gives 15, I am still having trouble identifying the fault due to the newness of the terms.
**Solution i wrote** (works)

```
    String n = "762";
    BigInteger t = new BigInteger(n);
    BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    System.out.println(t);
    int solution =0;       
    while(!t.equals(one)){
        if(t.equals(three)){
            t=t.subtract(one);
            solution++;
        }
        if(((t.and(one)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))){
            t=t.shiftRight(1);
            solution++;  
            }
        else if((t.and(one)).equals(BigInteger.ONE)&&
(((t.shiftRight(1).and(one))).equals(BigInteger.ONE))){
            t=t.add(one);
            solution++;

        }
        else 
if(t.and(one).shiftRight(1).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)&&t.and(one).equals(one)){
            t=t.subtract(one);            
            solution++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(solution);
}

}
```

Comment: How does it fail? Give a concrete example. Do you know the exact threshold of failure?

Comment: Edit all relevant information into your question to make it complete. This does not really explain why you think it fails btw.

Comment: BTW, I'm going to guess just out of my @s$ that the minimum is something like `k + (n - 2^k)` where `n` is your number and `k = floor(log2(n))`.

Comment: `k` is the number of divisions by 2, and `n - 2^k` is how far the number is from a power of 2, i.e., how many subtractions you need along the way to make the numbers come out even.

Comment: On second thought it's probably the min of `k + n - 2^k` and `l + 2^l - n`, where `l` is `ceil(log2(n))`, and n, k are as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of **bit manipulation**, as hinted by the divide by 2 rule.

Lets look at the number `762` (base 10), aka `1011111010` (base 2), that was mentioned in a comment *(now deleted)*.

Division by 2 means to shift the bits to the right. Presumably you're not allowed to do that unless number is divisible by 2, i.e. the rightmost bit is 0.

So, if we can shift right, we do it. If not, we can subtract one to clear the bit.

However, if the next bit at also 1, we can instead add 1, so multiple 1 bits are flipped to 0 in one operation, e.g. `100111 + 1 = 101000`.

As a special consideration, `11` should not add `1`, since that would go `11` → `100` → `10` → `1`, i.e. 3 operations. Instead you subtract `1` to get `11` → `10` → `1`.

```
          1011111010
 1:  /2 =  101111101
 2:  -1 =  101111100
 3:  /2 =   10111110
 4:  /2 =    1011111
 5:  +1 =    1100000
 6:  /2 =     110000
 7:  /2 =      11000
 8:  /2 =       1100
 9:  /2 =        110
10:  /2 =         11
11:  -1 =         10
12:  /2 =          1
```

Solution found in **12** operations.

Now you just have to write the code for it.

Comment: @Oleg Just made it up, but I've seen similar challenges, so wasn't a big leap. First time with both `+1` and `-1` as options, I think.

Comment: I would add, that for the `+1` operation there should be at least 3 `1`s... Or else your "special consideration" would kick in...

Comment: I wrote the code for it but bitwise operation is still new to me.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto It's ok to do `+1` for just two `1`s, except if they are the last two. E.g. `10011` +1 → `10100` → `1010` → `101` → `100` **vs.** `10011` -1 → `10010` → `1001` → `1000` → `100`. In both cases it took 4 steps to get to the same point, so you can do it either way, and just keeping special handling to a single `x == 3` check is easier. The only reason you have to handle 3 specially, is that adding 1 will make the number *longer* (in base 2). Even for 3 `1`s, without nothing else, it's a wash: `111` +1 → `1000` → `100` → `10` → `1` **vs.** `111` -1 → `110` → `11` → `10` → `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions

```
        (!((t.and(one)).shiftRight(1)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

and

```
        (!((t.and(one)).shiftRight(2)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

are wrong.  They were meant to test the second and third least-significant bits of `t` for non-zero, but they don't.  They simply return `false` every time.

Both expressions start with `t.and(one)`, which isolates the *last* bit of `t`, not the second-to-last or third-to-last.  Each then shifts that bit away, effectively leaving `BigInteger.ZERO`.  Both tests thus boil down to `BigInteger.ZERO.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)`, and because `BigInteger.ZERO` is never *not* equal to `BigInteger.ZERO`, the result is uniformly `false` regardless of what `t` was.

What you wanted was

```
        (!((t.shiftRight(1)).and(one)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

and

```
        (!((t.shiftRight(2)).and(one)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

Doing the shift *first* moves the desired bit of `t` into last position in a new `BigInteger`, before `.and(one)` isolates it for testing.  Now you're actually testing the second-to-last and third-to-last bits of `t`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my version of @Andreas bitwise method.

```
public static enum Op
{
    PLUS_1, MINUS_1, DIV_2
}
public static void shortest( final long value, final List<Op> steps )
{
    System.out.println( Long.toBinaryString( value ) );
    if ( value > 1L )
    {
        if ( ( value & 1L ) == 0L )
        {
            // last bit is 0
            steps.add( Op.DIV_2 );
            shortest( value / 2L, steps );
        }
        else if ( Long.highestOneBit( value ) == Long.bitCount( value ) )
        {
            // only 1 bits
            steps.add( Op.MINUS_1 );
            shortest( value - 1L, steps );
        }
        else if ( ( value & 3L ) == 3L )
        {
            // last bits are 11
            steps.add( Op.PLUS_1 );
            shortest( value + 1L, steps );
        }
        else
        {
            // last bits are 01
            steps.add( Op.MINUS_1 );
            shortest( value - 1L, steps );
        }
    }
}
public static void print( final long value, final List<Op> steps )
{
    System.out.printf( "%d = %<x = %s = %d %s\n", value, Long.toBinaryString( value ),
                       steps.size(), steps );
}
public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    final List<Op> steps = new ArrayList<>();
    shortest( 726, steps );
    print( 726, steps );

    steps.clear();
    shortest( 762, steps );
    print( 762, steps );
}
```

Output:

```
1011010110
101101011
101101100
10110110
1011011
1011100
101110
10111
11000
1100
110
11
10
1
726 = 2d6 = 1011010110 = 13 [DIV_2, PLUS_1, DIV_2, DIV_2, PLUS_1, DIV_2, DIV_2, PLUS_1, DIV_2, DIV_2, DIV_2, MINUS_1, DIV_2]
1011111010
101111101
101111100
10111110
1011111
1100000
110000
11000
1100
110
11
10
1
762 = 2fa = 1011111010 = 12 [DIV_2, MINUS_1, DIV_2, DIV_2, PLUS_1, DIV_2, DIV_2, DIV_2, DIV_2, DIV_2, MINUS_1, DIV_2]
```